# Get rid of or suppress the warning CGSReenableUpdate in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm running 10.10.5 Yosemite, and Xcode 6.4. I'm getting CGSReenableUpdate warning. The warning comes when I run my program, at unpredictable times. It looks like this

```
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate: unbalanced enable/disable update.
<Warning>: Backtrace (at 62127):                               
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate:  0   CoreGraphics                
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate:  1   CoreGraphics                
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate:  2   CoreGraphics                
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate:  3   CoreGraphics                
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate:  4   QuickLook                   
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate:  5   libdispatch.dylib           
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate:  6   libdispatch.dylib           
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate:  7   libdispatch.dylib           
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate:  8   libdispatch.dylib           
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate:  9   libdispatch.dylib           
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate:  10  libdispatch.dylib           
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate:  11  libsystem_pthread.dylib     
<Warning>: CGSReenableUpdate:  12  libsystem_pthread.dylib
```

Is there a way to suppress or get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 2):

I have also experienced this warning. My testing shows the following.

Warning only occurs on machines running OS X 10.10 with ATI or NVIDIA graphics.

Warning only occurs when opening sqlite or xml document. It does not occur when opening binary document.

Warning does not occur on OS X 10.7, 10.8, or 10.9 machines.

Warning does not occur with Intel graphics.

Filed Apple Bug Report 21040416 but no response yet.

Comment: I tried to search for that bug number at bugreporter.apple.com but I couldn't find it.  Will you give me directions on how to find the bug report?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this after making a change within `NSDocument`'s `readFromData` method. After lots of trial and error, I saw that the function throws an error, but I'd commented out all the throws. When I included a `throw` statement in the function, the crashes, including this one which also referenced QuickLook and dropbox for some reason, all went away.

I can't explain the cause and effect, but it's something to consider...